# Delete Contact through API

Tags: podio

We are trying to delete the contact from App using API but getting the below error:

{"error_propagate":false,"error":"forbidden","error_description":"The app with id 21103725 does not have the right delete on item with id 1250719299","request":{"url":"http://api.podio.com/item/1250719299","query_string":"","method":"DELETE"}}

Our application is using C# code with API “PodioAPI.Services”.
We have tried below methods to delete the contact but getting the same issue:
DeleteItem
BulkDeleteItems

Actually, the logic is when we add contact in application it sync to Podio and we can delete it. But when we sync contacts (created in PODIO) to out application and try to delete it, it throws above error.

Please let us know how can we assign permission to contact so we can delete from API.

Comment: Please confirm you are creating and deleting an item with same App authentication?. It seems to be an access issue.

Comment: 'The app with id 21103725 does not have the right delete on item with id 1250719299'. Is this App id is belongs to your contact app?